# Capture tap and hold on Mac trackpad with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a select list and when I tap and hold on my Mac trackpad, then two finger scroll and let go on an option in the list, jQuery doesn't register this as a click. Does anyone know how I can capture this action? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really interested in a click event or have you just been using the click event where you're really looking for the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

Comment: I can't use the change event because I'm using the jQuery selectmenu script which rewrites the select list as a UL and the option elements as LIs. Any suggestions with that?

Comment: @user310404: Have you tried using the change event? Looks like [selectmenu should support it](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js#L534) unless there is a bug in selectmenu.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons.

Reason 1: click hold and scroll is the same as click and drag

Reason 2: It's on click... not on release you have to be clicking down on the element first.